# Injecting factory into controller

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, factory

I have my app module defined like this in index.js.I am just creating the module and adding controller,factory associated with module.

```
import controller from './controllers/myAppController';
import factory from './controllers/myAppFactory';

angular.module("myApp" , [])
.config(..//code)
.controller('myAppCtrl',['$scope','myappFactroy',controller])
.factory('myappFactory',['$http',factory]);
```

myAppController.js

```
const myAppController= function($scope,factory) {
 $scope.myData= factory.getJsonFile(); //here am not getting the file
};

export default myAppController;
```

myAppFactory.js

```
const myAppFactory= function($http) {

    function getJsonFile (){
        $http.get('/sample/app/mock-data/test.json').success(function(data) {
          return data;
        }).error(function(){
            alert("Error in getting the file");
        });
    }

    return{
        getJsonFile:getJsonFile
    };

};

export default myAppFactory;
```

Issue:

1) Am getting the data in factory like [object][object].But in controller i am not getting the data. $scope.myData is undefine.

Questions:

1) While defining angular.module should i need to change the order of defining controller and module. ie. factory should be defined first and then controller since controller is dependent on factory ?

```
eg: angular.module("myApp",[])
.config()
.factory()
.controller();
```

2) If my factory need $http, should i need to inject it in my controller also since its going to call the factory method ?

3) What is the best way to parse the json response received and get the data from it.

Comment: 1. Order doesn't metter 2. No, you don't need to inject `$http` into controller.

Comment: you can use parsing library Papaparser which can  parse csvData (from anything to everything) to JSON.

Comment: Parsing is happening fine..I am not getting data from factory to controller..I think there is some issue while calling factory form controller.

Comment: Did you console the myData inside controller after getting the data from the factory method ?